# How to change DateTime UTC in WCF service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service returning opening and closing times.
The problem is that the time is always represented with UTC+2.
Here's an example of my WCF code:

```
[XmlElementAttribute(Form = Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "time", Order = 1)]
public System.DateTime OpeningTime
{
    get
    {
        string timeString = "10:00:00";
        return XmlConvert.ToDateTime(timeString, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);
    }
}
```

The result in the response is:

```
<OpeningTime>10:00:00.0000000+02:00</ClosingTime>
```

But I need it with UTC 0 like

```
<ClosingTime>10:00:00.0000000+00:00</ClosingTime>
```

I have no clue how I can specify the timezone. I also tried using ToLocalTime() but it is always UTC+2.

I need the time as DateTime so converting the DateTime to string is no option.

Comment: If you want it in UTC, why are you using `XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind` rather than `XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc`?

Comment: (Although I'd argue that a time (but no date) is an odd thing to have with a time zone anyway. Normally you'd have a *local* time, with no time zone information...)

Comment: Even if I use XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc, the response time has UTC+2.

Comment: So have you looked at what the `Kind` is of the `DateTime` returned by the property? Basically there are two levels of conversion going on: from `string` to `DateTime`, and then from `DateTime` back to string...

Comment: With XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind the kind is unspecified and with XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc it's UTC.

Comment: Right. `DateTime` really doesn't have enough information for "Roundtrip" to be valid, but for UTC I'd expect it to be okay. So at least we know that the problem is in the conversion of the `DateTime` *back* into a `string`...